# 2 of my blender files that I have been working on crash as soon as i try to open them. My other files still open and i can open a new one as well

Tags: blend-files

**Laptop Specs**

**Hardware Overview:**

Model Name:   MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: MacBookPro17,1
Model Number: MYD92LL/A
Chip: Apple M1
Total Number of Cores:    8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
Memory:   8 GB
System Firmware Version:  10151.41.12
OS Loader Version:    10151.41.12
Serial Number (system):   FVFF56FFQ05F
Hardware UUID:    4B912DC4-BD08-5BA2-A1AB-BFB773429A10
Provisioning UDID:    00008103-000605383AE2001E
Activation Lock Status:   Disabled

**System Software Overview:**

System Version:   macOS 14.1.1 (23B81)
Kernel Version:   Darwin 23.1.0
Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD
Boot Mode:    Normal
Computer Name:    Elvis’s MacBook Pro
Username: Elvis Monteiro (hunt)
Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
System Integrity Protection:  Enabled
Time since boot:  1 hour

**Storage:** 320GB left out of 500GB

**Issue:**

A couple of my .blend files refuse to open and crash immediately when i try to do so. I'm still able to open other files that I worked on, even ones that i created before these two. I have tried restarting my laptop and also tried creating more storage space by transferring files to my ssd. Nothing has worked.I'm not very good at computers and I'd really appreciate it if someone could look into this and help me get back the long hours i put into these projects.

Here's a screenshot of the blender crash report down below:

[image: Blender Crash Report]

Comment: Have you tried to open a new file and append the collections or objects of the broken file with the menu *File > Append ...*?

Answer (score 3):

What can be a solution is to open a new file and append the objects from the corrupted one.